# How to make a box that will Expand to fit content, but stop expanding when remaining space is filled?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm in flutter. I have a `layout`, which has a `pageview.builder`, and each page shows a card. I'd like the card to fit the content, expanding for cards with more content, up until the card fills the rest of the page, at which point I'd want to it start scrolling. I've spent a few hours trying different nestings of `layouts`, but I can't work out the combination to achieve my desired effect.

The `code` looks something like this :

```
child: new Column(
        children: [

          SizedBox(
            height: 25.0,
          ),
          Image.asset(
            "images/image.png",
            scale: 0.1,
            height: 100.0,
          ),
          new ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 550.0),
              child: PageView.builder(
                controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.9),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                  DayInfo thisDay = AllDaysInfo[index];
                      child: Material(
                          child: new Text(thisDay.info),
                          )
                      )
                 )
        ]
),
```

(`parentheses` may not be correct! Have cut my code down code to make it a bit easier to see what I'm doing)

So, I want to remove the `ConstrainedBox`, which is essentially forcing it to be `550` high. I want that to allow it to fill the remaining space, but stop growing when it gets there!

Any ideas?

Mike

Answer (score 1):

So - I've worked it out! Sorry - this was kind of dumb. Essentially all I needed to do was add an `Expanded` widget, instead of the `ConstrainedBox` in the above example, and put a `SingleChildScrollView` widget around the `Material` widget. Works a charm!

```
child: new Column(
        children: [

          SizedBox(
            height: 25.0,
          ),
          Image.asset(
            "images/image.png",
            scale: 0.1,
            height: 100.0,
          ),
          new Expanded(
              child: PageView.builder(
                controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.9),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                  DayInfo thisDay = AllDaysInfo[index];
                      child: SingleChildScrollView
                             child: Material(
                                    child: new Text(thisDay.info),
                                    )
                             )
                      )
                 )
        ]
),
```